# SDDM login screen showing wrong time format

Tags: linux, locale, sddm

first thing: I'm using KDEneon as system, no particular mods.
I have a small problem is really small but is bothering me...
I set system-wide English language, but than something puzzling happen.
The 12h time format was bothering me pretty much, so I set on the system settings `C` as time format (Settings->Regional Settings->Formats) and the login screen was not changing the time format.

I found that I need to change the `locale` settings, so I opened and modified `etc/default/locale` and under `LC_TIME=`I put as well `C`. It worked for a while, but after a while it got broken.

Anyone can tell me what could have went wrong or if the SDDM login screen is related to a different config file for setting date and time format?
Any help for troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a solution. I'm running the KDE-spin of Fedora 38. I'm not 100% why, but you have to use localectl to change settings for SDDM. This includes the keyboard layout (which also was a problem for me).

I was using `de_AT.UTF-8` on my system, but when I ran `localectl` I got:

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: sv-latin1
   X11 Layout: sv, at
  X11 Variant: ,
```

You can use `localectl list-locales` to list all available ones. As I live in Austria I opted for `de_AT.UTF-8`, so running the following helped me:

```
localectl set-locale de_AT.UTF-8
```

I hope it will help you out!